# Preventing Video Playing lag in Flash

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Flash applications so sluggish in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852/why-are-flash-applications-so-sluggish-in-ubuntu)

I have just installed Ubuntu for a friend. He uses 32 bit. When he views YouTube videos full-screen there is a kind of lag. He is using an ATI 1 GB graphics card. This doesn't happen when he is not in full screen mode. Is there any workaround to prevent this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A better video card might help.

Comment: its probably something around there maybe drivers :)

Comment: I don't think the Video card is at play - I've had smooth flash on crappier cards than that.

Comment: OK.  It's something usually reported with Intel graphics.

Comment: A graphics card did help.