# Is there a WINE version of Flash as a plugin to Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: performance, firefox, wine, flash

I've seen [complaints](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852/why-are-flash-applications-so-sluggish-in-ubuntu) about flash performance. Would it be possible to use WINE as a plugin to firefox in order to get better performance out of flash? (Hopefully WINE would utilize some sort of hardware optimizations) Would using WINE even give better performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

At best you could get this to work by running the whole browser in wine but that would be sure to decrease performance not increase performance.

The best way to overcome poor flash performance is to download videos instead of streaming them using tools such as [abby](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/abby/) (also: [clive](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/clive), [cclive](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cclive), [youtube-dl](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/youtube-dl/)). All of these are available from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: Well, my question unfortunately applies to non-video as well. :( (this isn't to knock what you wrote - in fact I found that very useful, it just won't completely cut it for me.)

Answer (score 5):

The best performance change I've made for Flash is to install a flash blocking extension (e.g. [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gofhjkjmkpinhpoiabjplobcaignabnl), Opera (builtin at opera:config#UserPrefs|EnableOnDemandPlugin), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433/)).

When I have 150 or more tabs open (not so uncommon for me) – or even just 20 :) – this really helps, yet I can still click to run any Flash applet I must use.

Answer (score 2):

It won't help. The main problem with flash is that it can't use xv output and Wine won't help you with that. Pulseaudio also seems to help with bad flash performance, so you could try a different sound server. I wasn't successful with that on Lucid tho.

For YouTube, Vimeo and Blip.tv you could use my FlashVideoReplacer extension, which replaces the embedded video with available mp4 in order to play it with other plugins. CPU usage is reduced a lot.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/161869/

Also see my tutorial on flash optimization for other alternatives:

http://firefox-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/05/flash-optimization.html

Answer (score 2):

Pipelight! It's running flash, shockwave, silverlight and unity player through wine http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Go for  "lovinglinux" tutorial , i tried FlashVideoReplacer extension and it worked like a charm . thank you "lovinglinux" =)

Comment: Could you include a link?  Do you mean [this](http://flvideoreplacer-extension.blogspot.com/)?

Comment: yes,thats what i meant ,"lovinglinux" the user who gave the third comment , try his tutorial at http://bit.ly/d6S2P3 .

Comment: Link is dead now.

Answer (score 0):

Lets just cross our fingers that html5 will be the standard soon! For now use Chrome, Opera or Firefox4 beta and activate html5 on youtube. Works pretty well...