# Youtube videos are jerky...?

Tags: 10.04, video, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Flash applications so sluggish in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852/why-are-flash-applications-so-sluggish-in-ubuntu)

Lately ALL my videos are jerky (using 10.04)...I have a Nvidia 5200 card with driver 173...All videos are getting worse than when I first loaded 10.04 on my computer...I don't understand why...???
Robert

Answer (score 1):

What is your CPU and are you using the x64 version of Ubuntu? And is this jerkiness repeated on all Flash video sites?

As a temporary solution, you might want to consider switching YouTube to HTML5 `<video>` mode using [this page](http://www.youtube.com/html5), but you will almost certainly need to install Google Chrome for it to work.

Comment: The version of Firefox in 10.04 should also support the <video> tag.

Comment: It does, but it supports neither WebM or H.264, which are the video formats YouTube uses. It works fine for .ogg video, but not for YouTube videos.

Comment: No...I am using x32 version with Nvidia FX5200 card and I already usw Google Chrome...Robert

Comment: Could we have more information about the specifications of your computer? CPU, RAM, age, desktop/notebook, etc? Do you have the "extra" desktop effects running?