# Why is my video playback always bad?

Tags: video, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Flash applications so sluggish?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852/why-are-flash-applications-so-sluggish)

I am wondering, why is the HD video playback under Linux so bad? I mean, HD videos are laggy . I've tested many distos, on multiple PCs, but compared to Windows, the HD playback is always bad. Laggy all the time, and the online video playback? It's much worse. I tried both nvidia and amd video cards, the latest official drivers, even the open source drivers, but the HD playback performance is......

AMD E-300 with Radeon HD6310 (384 MB of RAM) Graphics, 4GB DDR3. The GPU is integrated, but I can run HD content on Windows without a problem, both locally and online, with flash player. I've tried many distros. Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Linux Mint, Arch Linux, ArchBang, Fedora, SuSE. They all have the same problem, laggy flash playback, even at 480p!

I really want to stick with Linux, but I can't because of this fact. Do you have any tips? Is there a secret that I don't know? Just tell me please.

Comment: I have not a single problem watching H10P video's with SMPlayer and/or VLC on a system that has an Radeon HD6650. See caesiums like and please answer the "Can you confirm hardware assisted decoding is actually being used at all?" question ;)

Comment: Hello. Rinzwind, the problem I have is not just locally; Like I said, HD playback with flash-player is much worse.

Answer (score 2):

without having your distro etc and hardware info its hard to help with this.
i have a nvidia card running ubuntu 12.04 and the latest Gnome-shell 3.3.4 and HD playback with VLC Mplayer is really smoth. have you tried a newer kernel and the x-org-edgers ppa?

Comment: AMD E-300 with Radeon HD6310 (384 MB of RAM) Graphics, 4GB DDR3. The GPU is integrated, but I can run HD content on Windows without a problem, both locally and online, with flash player. I've tried many distros. Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Linux Mint, Arch Linux, ArchBang, Fedora, SuSE. They all have the same problem, laggy flash playback, even at 480p!

Comment: what do you have installed at the moment? Ubuntu? if so try this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: just saw this on the ubuntu forums http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1915488

Comment: lilt rant here: THAT is the problem, i want to play the video not have to spend the afternoon fixing drivers and cocdes and what not