# Problem when fullscreen Youtube or Vimeo videos ubuntu 12.04 only

Tags: 12.04

when I fullscreen youtube or vimeo videos in ubuntu 12.04 they get laggy. I didn't have this problem when I was using Ubuntu 11.10. I know it might be something with flash, but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks. Also I'm using google chrome, I also try it in mozilla firefox and I get the same problem. This is happening with VIMEO and YOUTUBE.

Comment: I've noticed this mostly only happens with HTML5 videos on YouTube. It may be something in Firefox, or the way YouTube is streaming the video.

Comment: I would install Chromium(Google Chrome Web Browser) and see if the same thing happens. If it does not then it can very well be a FireFox issue.

Comment: Also do you have the ubuntu-restricted-extras installed?

Comment: I'm using google chrome and yes I tried chromium already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are Flash applications so sluggish?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/852/why-are-flash-applications-so-sluggish)

Comment: This question appears to be about Ubuntu 12.04 only which is EOL. OP hasn't signed on in ~5 years and problem may have gone away on its own. VTC as `not reproducible`.