# Youtube runs very slowly on all web browsers Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, video, flash, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Flash applications so sluggish?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852/why-are-flash-applications-so-sluggish)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS last week, and it has been running fine. However, whenever I try to view a video on YouTube, there are huge amounts of lag, with the picture often freezing when in full-screen mode. The videos however appear to be loading as normal. I have no such issues in Windows 7. My graphics card is an Nvidia Geforce 8600M GT. I installed the standard proprietary driver for it in Ubuntu's additional drivers section before I ever attempted to view videos, and it has a green light next to it indicating it is active. However, when I go to system information, the graphics card is listed as unknown, and the additional drivers app describes it only as a Geforce rather than the specific model number. This problem occurs in all 3 browsers I have tried - Firefox, Chrome and Chromium. I had flash player installed when attempting in Firefox and Chromium, and it is built into Chrome and was activated. I have not yet tried to view videos from any other source. How can I resolve this?