# Why does Flash freeze Ubuntu & Firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash

Pages like this that have many embedded videos, freeze Ubuntu for a long time, then Flash crashes.

Is this just a Ubuntu 64-bit problem? Do I need more than my current 2gb ram? http://www.deanstalk.net/deanstalk/video/

I'm surprised that it can completely freeze up Firefox, since Firefox uses a separate process for plugins? Should this be reported as a bug, in Firefox, or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly if you look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852/why-are-flash-applications-so-sluggish-crashy), people everywhere experience this (including me), on higher and lower end pc's, it's most probably something Adobe should add to the top of their priority list but HTML5 is also something web-publishers should start adding to theirs, too..

Sometimes my Firefox shuts down or experiences horrific lag and I'm on a dual core Intel with 4gb RAM.