# Ubuntu 13.04 Youtube/Video Freeze

Tags: freeze, youtube

I seem to be having an issue in which video [youtube or otherwise] will cause the system to completely freeze. Does anybody know how to fix this or what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Try to open [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTl3U6aSd2w&html5=True) (is a Youtube video of a commercial that should use HTML5 instead of Flash). Your system also freezes playing this video?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are Flash applications so sluggish/crashy?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/852/why-are-flash-applications-so-sluggish-crashy)

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu disables some 3rd party sources, which might include some flash playback.

Go to your dash, search for "Software & Updates". Try to check "Proprietary drivers", "Software restricted by copyright" and go to Other Software to check software from "Canonical Partners" and "Independent" which is some third-party software as well.